# Price on request back to normal 0.00 multistore

Tags: product, price, template

Some while ago I added this code to show "price on request" instead of 0.00

/app/design/frontend/default/yourtemplate/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.html.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
  <?php echo '<b>Prijs op Aanvraag<b><br><br>'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I need to change it back to normal
So I've uploaded the complete original filemap "catalog"

However: only on the mainsite the priceview is back to normal
The rest of the shops still show "price on request".
No price is showing up, even when it's not 0.00 (only in shoppingcart)

Probably there is an other file or shop setting involved. 
Can someone help me to get my prices back?

Comment: Solved it myself.

Comment: manufacturer's "minimum advertised price was "ON".